# Why is my Python class not callable?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to write OO Python code the same way I learned in Java and that's probably where I'm going south. I have a main script and a class that somebody else wrote that I adapted. I call the class in the main script but every technique I use I get [class name] is not callable.

Below is the most recent attempt. This is the main script. The variable directoryPairs has been removed for security.

```
import yaml
import pysftp
import FingerprintKey

with open('config/config.yaml') as settings:
    cfg = yaml.load(settings)

host = cfg['host']
username = cfg['username']
password = cfg['password']
serverkey = cfg['fingerPrint']

x = FingerprintKey(serverkey)

options = pysftp.CnOpts()
options.hostkeys.clear()
options.hostkeys.add('www.example.com', u'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384', x)

with pysftp.Connection(host, username=username, password=password, cnopts=options) as sftp:
    #for source, destination in directoryPairs.items():
        #sftp.get_d(source, destination, preserve_mtime=True)
        #if sftp.exists(source):
            #files = sftp.listdir(source)
            #for f in files:
                #sftp.remove(os.path.join(source, f))
    sftp.close()
```

Below is the class FingerprintKey.py

```
import hashlib as hl


def trim_fingerprint(fingerprint):
    if fingerprint.startswith('ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 384 '):
        return fingerprint[len('ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 384 '):]
    return fingerprint


def clean_fingerprint(fingerprint):
    return trim_fingerprint(fingerprint).replace(':', '')


class FingerprintKey:

    def __init__(self, fingerprint):
        self.fingerprint = clean_fingerprint(fingerprint)

    def compare(self, other):
        if callable(getattr(other, "get_fingerprint", None)):
            return other.get_fingerprint() == self.fingerprint
        elif clean_fingerprint(other) == self.get_fingerprint():
            return True
        elif hl.md5(other).digest().encode('hex') == self.fingerprint:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return self.compare(other)

    def __contains__(self, other):
        return self.compare(other)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.compare(other)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.compare(other)

    def get_fingerprint(self):
        return self.fingerprint

    def get_name(self):
        return u'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384'

    def asbytes(self):
         # Note: This returns itself.
         #   That way when comparisons are done to asbytes return value,
         #   this class can handle the comparison.
        return self
```

Both of these files are in the same directory.

Comment: In your main script, `FingerprintKey` refers to the module with that name. The class (with the same name) within that module is referred to as `FingerprintKey.FingerprintKey`.

Comment: OH! Ok. So it's not like Java where you have to name the file the same as the class.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1) I made the following additions to the code and it worked.

I renamed the class file to AuthOnFingerPrint

```
import AuthOnFingerPrint
options.hostkeys.add('www.example.com', u'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 384 ', AuthOnFingerPrint.FingerprintKey(serverkey))
```